# The integral of $ \int_{0}^{1} 2^{x^2 +x} dx$

Tags: integration

So, What I tried was,

$$ I(b) =  \int_{0}^{1} 2^{x^2 + x +b} dx$$

And hence,

$$ I'(b) = \ln(2)  I$$

Hence,

$$ I = C_o 2^{b}$$

or,

$$ C2^{b} = \int_{0}^{1} 2^{x^2 +x + b} dx$$

Now I'm trying to find an easy 'b' to evaluate the right side integral at, so as to figure out my constant. However I'm not sure how to find that 'b'. A guess was to take $ b= \frac{1}{4}$ however that was not a fruitful substitution

Comment: I'm assuming this goes along the lines of the feynman trick?

Comment: yes haha :D it does

Comment: I don't think there's a way to avoid the imaginary error function here (in other words - no closed form in terms of elementary functions), but what do I know.

Comment: The integral does not have an elementary answer because it is equivalent to $$2^{-\frac{1}{4}}\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{3}{2}}e^{x^2\log 2}\:dx$$

Comment: I have seen some non integral functions integrated using feynmans

Comment: I think you're mixing up the ideas. Those integrals may have had nonelementary *antiderivatives*, but the *definite integrals* with specific bounds had elementary answers. This function has both nonelementary antiderivative *and* definite integral.

Comment: The answer to definite integral is elementary..

Comment: It is not. As Jyrki Lahtonen said, it is imaginary error function. You're free to refute [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+2%5E%28x%5E2%2Bx%29+dx+from+0+to+1) if you can.

Comment: I mean as in there exists an actual value over those specific bounds.

Comment: An actual value (meaning convergence) $\neq$ elementary. Use numerical methods if you want to get a decimal approximation. An analytical answer with elementary functions is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$\int{2^{x^{2} + x} d x} = \int{e^{\left(x^{2} + x\right) \ln{\left(2 \right)}} dx}$$
Completing the square,

$$\int{\frac{2^{\frac{3}{4}} e^{\left(x \sqrt{\ln{\left(2 \right)}} + \frac{\sqrt{\ln{\left(2 \right)}}}{2}\right)^{2}}}{2} d x}$$

If
$$t=x \sqrt{\ln{\left(2 \right)}} + \frac{\sqrt{\ln{\left(2 \right)}}}{2} \to dx = \frac{dt}{\sqrt{\ln{\left(2 \right)}}}$$
Hence,
$$\int{\frac{2^{\frac{3}{4}} e^{t^{2}}}{2 \sqrt{\ln{\left(2 \right)}}} d t} = \frac{2^{\frac{3}{4}} \displaystyle\int{e^{t^{2}} d t}}{2 \sqrt{\ln{\left(2 \right)}}}$$

and the integral of $e^{t^{2}}$does not have a closed form, and occour to use imaginary error function called $\text{erfi}$. After you can calculate the definite integral.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use special functions, build a series expansion around $x=\frac 12$ to get for the integrand
$$2^{3/4} \left(1+2 L \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)+L (2 L+1) \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{2}{3}
   L^2 (2 L+3) \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^3+\frac{1}{6} L^2 (4 L^2+12L+3)
   \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^4+L^3\left(\frac{4 L^2}{15}+\frac{4 L}{3}+1\right)
   \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^5+O\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^6\right) \right)$$ where $L=\log(2)$.

Integrate termwise and an *approximation* is
$$\int_{0}^{1} 2^{x^2 +x} dx \sim \frac{480+40 L+83 L^2+12 L^3+4 L^4 } {240 \sqrt[4]{2} }\approx 1.93589$$ while the exact solution is $1.93749$.

For sure, adding terms will improve the accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a (**failed**) attempt using the Leibniz rule (a.k.a. Feynman's trick).
First changee variables (Ninad comment);  the problem is equaivalent to
evaluating
$$
\int_{1/4}^{3/4} e^{(\log 2) x^2}dx .
$$
Let
$$
F(b) = \int_{1/4}^{3/4} e^{b x^2}dx
$$
We want to evaluate $F(\log 2)$.
Differentiate (using the Leibniz rule)
$$
F'(b) = \int_{1/4}^{3/4} x^2e^{b x^2}dx
$$
Integrate by parts
$$
F'(b) = \frac{3e^{9b/4} - e^{b/4}}{4b} - \frac{1}{b^2}\int_{1/4}^{3/4}e^{b x^2}dx
$$
So $F$ satisfies the differential equation
$$
F'(b)+\frac{1}{b^2}F(b) = \frac{3e^{9b/4} - e^{b/4}}{4b} .
\tag{1}$$
Now the homogeneous equation
$$
G'(b)+\frac{1}{b^2}G(b) = 0
$$
is easily solved, $G(b) = Ce^{1/b}$, the inhomogeneous
DE $(1)$ is not so easy.  The solution
$e^{1/b}$ is not of the proper form in order to use **undetermined coefficients**.  We can always try **variation of parameters**; but there are integrals in there, and they turn out to be just as hard as the original problem!
$$
F(b) = Ce^{1/b} + e^{1/b}
\int \frac{3 e^{(9b^2-4)/(4b)}-e^{(b^2-4)/(4b)}}{4b} \;db
$$